# ngShow and Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, ng-show

I am trying to add a Bootstrap modal to my Angular module.  But when I click on the button to show the modal nothing happens.  Any help would be useful.

Here's part of my controller

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria']);

app.controller('LocationController', ['StorageService', '$scope', '$mdSidenav', '$mdDialog', function (StorageService, $scope, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog) {

      var locationCtrl = this;
    . . . 
    openEmailDialog: function (email) {
          locationCtrl.ViewModel.emailDialog = true;
    },
```

Here is part of my html page.

```
<md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="locationCtrl.Actions.openEmailDialog(location)"
                           ng-show="locationCtrl.ViewModel.emailButton == true">Send Email</md-button>
```

Here is the modal class:

```
<div class="modal" ng-show="locationCtrl.ViewModel.emailDialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="locationCtrl.Actions.closeEmailDialog()">&times;</button>
        <h3>To email this location please enter an email below </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Send email to" style="width:95%;" ng-model="locationCtrl.ViewModel.composeEmail.to"><br />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" ng-click="locationCtrl.ViewModel.Actions.closeEmailDialog()">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendEmail()">Send</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide full code for you controller? From the pasted code it is hard to say where openEmailDialog function is assigned to... Is it assigned to this.Actions.openEmailDialog? or to this.openEmailDialog?

Comment: it's assigned to Actions, like this:  locationCtrl.Actions = {